# vertex coordinates change whern use vtkOBJImporter and vtkOBJExporter

Tags: python, vtk

I have an OBJ file. When I open it with a text editor, I find that it has 38,000 vertices. But when I use vtkObjExporter to export a new OBJ file, I find that the vertex coordinates have become more than 224,000, and the point accuracy is highA lot. When I used vtkOBJImporter to load the OBJ model and printed the NumberOfPoints of polydata, I found that there were also more than 224,000 point coordinates. So I guess that something was done to the vertex coordinates when using vtkOBJImporter. It feels like using the coordinates of one point for multiple patches. Because it is used multiple times, the point data becomes more.
How should I keep the vertex coordinates the same as the original OBJ file?